# Performance monitoring all layers of a system

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I use several loadtesting tools (Loadrunner, JMeter, NeoLoad) to performance test different applications. Im wondering if it is possible to monitor all layers of an application stack so for example. Say i have the following data chain.

Loadbalancer <-x-> Application Server <-x-> RMI <-x-> Java Application  <-x-> MQ <-x-> Legacy application <-x-> Database

Where i have marked the `x` in the chain i am interested in monitoring, for example avg responsetimes.

Obviously we could simply create a wrapper on all endpoints which would gather the statistics for us and maybe we could import it into loadrunner or other loadtesting tools and sideline hem with the tools inbuilt performance statistics, but maybe there is tools/applications which already does this?

If not, how should we proceed, in order to gather this kind of statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard for this was supposed to be [Application Response Measurement (ARM)](http://www.opengroup.org/management/arm/). It was a cross language set of APIs that did just what you were looking for. The issue is that the products that implement this spec all tend to be big, expensive "enterprise" level monitoring tools. Think multi-week installs, consultants, more infrastructure and lots of buzzwords.

Still, if this is a mission critical app with a mission critical budget, this may be what you need. But you may be able to build your own that does just enough without too much effort. A quick search turns up at least one [open source ARM implementation](http://open-arm.sourceforge.net) if you still want to use that API.

Another option is to simply to have transactions you can run against each tier of the system to check general responsiveness. For example you can have a static web page on the LB, a no-op tx on the app server, a "hello" servlet on the Java app, put a message directly on the queue, etc. During a performance / load test, these could be hit directly by the load testing tool or you could write a wrapper servlet / application call that does this as a single HTTP (RMI?) call. Running these a few times a minute won't add too much load to the system, but it should help you pinpoint which tier is slower. The nice thing about this approach is that it also works in production, just watch out for security issues.

For single user kind of test, where you know you have problem (e.g. this tx is "slow"), I have also had pretty good luck with network tracing. It's very tedious, but when you aren't sure what tier is slow, starting up a network trace on a few machines and running a single tx usually gives a good idea of what the system is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I have handled this decomposition a number of ways in the past.   The first is at a very low level using protocol analyzer dumped data to find the time points where a conversation leaves tier X and enters tier Y.   The second method is through the use of log examination for the various tiers.   Something that can make your examination quite usefule in this case is a common log server for all of your components (syslog, Rsyslog, etc....) and a nice log parsing tool, such as the freely available Microsoft Logparser.   The third method utilization of the audit trail for an application stored in the database.  You may find this when working on enterprise services bus style applications which have a consumer/producer model and a bus to pass information rather than a direct connection.   The audit trails I have seen are typically stored in a database and allow the tracking of an individual transaction through the entire application infrastructure.   Your Load balancer, as a network device, may be out of the hunt on this one.

Note, if you go the protocol analyzer or log route, then be sure and synchronize all of your source information devices to a common time server.  Having one of your collectors (analyzer, app log) off on a time stamp basis can really be a hair pulling experience when you get into the analysis phase.

As to how you move from your collected data into LoadRunner, that part is very mechanical.   The Analysis program supports an interface to import external datapoints.    The format is very specific and is documented in both help and the online docs.  This import process works very well, as I often have to use it for collection of statistics from hosts which I do not have direct monitoring access to, but which need to be included as a part of the monitored test infrastructure.

James Pulley

Moderator (YahooGroups LoadRunner, Advanced-Loadrunner; GoogleGroups lr-LoadRunner; Linkedin LoadRunner, LoadRunnerByTheHour; SQAForums LoadRunner, WinRunner)